# Why SQLite indexes inequalities are limited to the right most position?

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing

The [docs](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html#where_clause_analysis) below indicate that inequalities(`<`, `>` signs) can only appear in the right most position of the index in order for it to be used. Why is it limited like that?

> All terms of the WHERE clause are analyzed to see if they can be
>   satisfied using indices. To be usable by an index a term must be of
>   one of the following forms:
>
> - column = expression
> - column IS expression
> - column > expression
> - column >= expression
> - column < expression
> - column <= expression
> - expression = column
> - expression > column
> - expression >= column
> - expression < column
> - expression <= column
> - column IN (expression-list)
> - column IN (subquery)
> - column IS NULL
>
> If an index is created using a statement like this:
>
> `CREATE INDEX idx_ex1 ON ex1(a,b,c,d,e,...,y,z);`
>
> Then the index might
>   be used if the initial columns of the index (columns a, b, and so
>   forth) appear in WHERE clause terms. The initial columns of the index
>   must be used with the *=* or *IN* or *IS* operators. **The right-most
>   column that is used can employ inequalities**. For the right-most column
>   of an index that is used, there can be up to two inequalities that
>   must sandwich the allowed values of the column between two extremes.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original question.

You are misreading the documentation.  It is saying that the inequality must be on the *right-most* column **in the index** that is used.

That is, if the index is `(a, b, c, d, e)`, then these are allowed:

- `a < 10`
- `a = 10 and b > 10`
- `a = 10 and b = 10 and c between 1 and 9`

However, this is not allowed:

- `b > 10`

The ordering in the `where` clause should have no impact on whether the index can be used.

Note that some databases can use an index for `b > 10` in this case.  That is called a skip-scan operation and not many databases support it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. You are right. I edited the question. I would like to know why the index is limited like that?